# convert JSON from ajax request to JSON object in java

Tags: java, json, gson

This is the form data

```
selectedDtlId: [{"id":"3","isReviewed":true,"notes":"notes asdf test add 2"},{"id":"2","isReviewed":true,"notes":""},{"id":"1","isReviewed":true,"notes":""}]
isReviewedAll: true
notesAll:
```

Upon running the below code in the Controller

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(request.getParameter("selectedDtlId"));
```

response

```
"[{\"id\":\"3\",\"isReviewed\":true,\"notes\":\"notes asdf test add 2\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"isReviewed\":true,\"notes\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"1\",\"isReviewed\":true,\"notes\":\"\"}]"
```

Expected resoponse

```
[
   {
      "id": "3",
      "isReviewed": true,
      "notes": "notes asdf test add 2"
   },
   {
      "id": "2",
      "isReviewed": true,
      "notes": ""
   },
   {
      "id": "1",
      "isReviewed": true,
      "notes": ""
   }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling toJson when you should be calling fromJson:

```
gson.fromJson(request.getParameter("selectedDtlId"), JsonElement.class);
```

Or if you have a model:

```
gson.fromJson(request.getParameter("selectedDtlId"), MyModel.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should map it to a Class. (Also you are calling toJson when you should call fromJson)

**Main**

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jsonInString = "[{\"id\":\"3\",\"isReviewed\":true,\"notes\":\"notes asdf test add 2\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"isReviewed\":true,\"notes\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"1\",\"isReviewed\":true,\"notes\":\"\"}]";
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    SelectedDtlId[] selectedDtlIds = gson.fromJson(jsonInString, SelectedDtlId[].class);

    for (SelectedDtlId selectedDtlId : selectedDtlIds) {
      System.out.println("id: " + selectedDtlId.getId());
      System.out.println("notes: " + selectedDtlId.getNotes());
      System.out.println("isReviewed: " + selectedDtlId.isReviewed());
    }
  }

}
```

**Model**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class SelectedDtlId {

  @SerializedName("id")
  private int id;
  @SerializedName("isReviewed")
  private boolean isReviewed;
  @SerializedName("notes")
  private String notes;

  // getters & setters
}
```

the result should be:

```
id: 3
notes: notes asdf test add 2
isReviewed: true
id: 2
notes: 
isReviewed: true
id: 1
notes: 
isReviewed: true
```

Comment: thanks Oguzcan, for detailed explanation. Your SelectedDtlId[] selectedDtlIds = gson.fromJson(jsonInString, SelectedDtlId[].class); helped me.